# How to maintain custom session for custom login and registration account module in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: magento-1.9, php, session, core-session

I am devoloping a module in which I am creating separate account which not using anything of customer. I am not able to create a separate session for my module . I tried to study customer module's session.php but i didn't get it. I am not understanding this code :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer'; 
}
```

Also Please Guide me how can i achieve it , Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: create you own session same as customer  just change namespace to your module

Comment: can i give any name here

Comment: yes. basically it will store as $_SESSION[$namespace]

Comment: ok sir thank you very much it cleared my doubt please suggest me any link or blog to read related to magento session

Comment: just google magento session handling

Answer (score 2):

for `customer` namespace, you can check here :  `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php`File.

it is namespace of your model, it holds for usage it like `Mage::getModel('customer/session)`.

So if your module named `yourCompany_yourModel` , you registered your `yourCompany_yourModel` model prefix in `config.xml` and created constructor as above in `app/code/local/yourCompany/yourModel/Model/Session.php`

if you make

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $namespace = 'yourModule'; 
        $this->init($namespace);
    }
```

then you can use it in your code like:

`Mage::getSingleton('yourModule/session')->setYourVariable($yourVar);`